# I want to create some zip files but they are always empty

Tags: php, zip

I want to download a ZIP file in which I stored some images but the downloaded files are empty (0 bytes)
My code looks mostly like:

```
$zipName = _DIR_CACHE . "/product_pictures" . date('Y-m-d') . '.zip';
$zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($productsFromSuppliers as $product)
{
    $barcode = $dbmProduct->getProductBarcode($product['product_id']) ?: $product['product_id'];
    $seoName = $dbmProduct->getProductSeoName($product['product_id']);
    $pictureIDs = $dbmModel->findSimple(['product_id' => $product['product_id']], '*', [Dbm_Model::OPT_DATASET => 'product_pictures']);
    $zip -> addEmptyDir($barcode);

    foreach ($pictureIDs as $pictureId)
    {
        $pictureName = Dbm_Picture::getPictureName($product['product_id'], $pictureId['picture_id']);
        $pictureUrl = Dbm_Picture::getPictureUrl($pictureName);
        ob_end_clean();
        $downloadedFileContents = file_get_contents($pictureUrl);
        $picturePath = _DIR_CACHE . '/' . $seoName . $pictureId['picture_id'];
        if($downloadedFileContents === false){
            Logger::warn('Failed to download file at: ' . $pictureUrl);
        }

        $newFile = $product['product_id'] . '.png';
        $save = file_put_contents($picturePath, $downloadedFileContents);

        if($save === false){
            Logger::warn('Failed to save file to: ' , $newFile);
        }
        $zip->addFile($picturePath, $barcode . '/' . $seoName . $pictureId['picture_id']);
        unlink($picturePath);
    }
}
$zip->close();
ob_end_clean();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($zipName));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipName));
readfile($zipName);

die();
```

My zips are always empty but I tested to see if the files are written correctly and they are. When I download them in my cache, the files are correct and whole.

Comment: And what is `_DIR_CACHE` set to?

Comment: I wouldn't unlink the files until after you close the zip.

Comment: Have you checked for errors? In the PHP error log?

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`